# Jquery change and control color on load and scroll

Tags: jquery

I need to check the background-color of the menu (#main-header) that must be equal to the color of the section (.section)when the page is loaded and when  scrolled, for now I only manage the scroll event.
When the page has been loaded the background-color of the menu is different from the background-color of the section.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stellac/w8xbzmne/3/

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($)
    {    
        $(window).scroll(function ()
        {
            if ($('.section').css('background-color') === '#fff') {
                $('#main-header').css('background-color','#fff');
            } else {
                $('#main-header').css('background-color','#001a22');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you question is not clear do you have any stackbliz or jsFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stellac/w8xbzmne/3/

Comment: @S.Chessa If the `.section.css('background-color')` never changes, then running that `if` statement more than once is pointless. You'll need to do some research about determining which `.section` is currently visible. However that's merely a guess; It's actually not really clear what you're asking because you haven't actually proposed any sort of question.

Comment: How can I make the color of the menu equal to the color of the section?

Comment: the sections can be either blue or white

Comment: If the content of the div is constant i mean the hight of each section is fixed, then you can get the view port on scroll event and get the current section call and apply the same to header

Comment: @S.Chessa Again, what is *"the section"*? Is there only one section? Or is it the first section? The last section? The one that's currently occupying most of the screen? The one that has most recently come on to the screen? The bottom-most visible one?  *See what I'm getting at?*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes care of changing the color and call that function on page load and in scroll event. So try something like this

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  changeColor();      //calling on page load
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    changeColor();    // calling in scroll event
  });
});

function changeColor() {
  if ($(".section").css("background-color") === "#fff") {
    $("#main-header").css("background-color", "#fff");
  } else {
    $("#main-header").css("background-color", "#001a22");
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be simplified to one line: `$(window).scroll(changeColor).scroll();` However, I think the *real* question that needs answering (that OP hasn't actually asked), is how to determine which `.section` is currently displaying on the page. The `if` statement doesn't make sense to include in a `scroll` event, as `if ($(".section").css("background-color") === "#fff")` will never change.

Comment: @TylerRoper Your one line statement, how do you call it for the first time when page finished loading? You are right about the `if` loop in `scroll` event. The OP could have changed the `#main-header`'s color within the `.section` update routine; that way no scroll event is required.

Comment: `.scroll(changeColor)` defines the listener. The `.scroll()` on the end executes it immediately after.